# Select that worked in previous Apache Ignite versions doesn't work in 2.8.0

Tags: ignite

I am using Apache Ignite 2.8.0. In old versions I was able to select node_attributes by regular select from cache.

```
SELECT t.VALUE FROM ignite.node_attributes t WHERE t.name = 'MONITOR_NODE'
```

In 2.8.0 this select not working for me anymore. Maybe there is some options in ignite I forgot to change? Or there is a different selection for node attributes?

Comment: Explain "not working": What results do you observe? Do you not get any results? An exception? Does your JVM suddenly vanish?

Comment: Query execution failed. Schema 'IGNITE' not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Apache Ignite` 2.8.0 you should use `SYS` schema to query node attributes.
Something like that:

`SELECT t.VALUE FROM sys.node_attributes t WHERE t.name = 'MONITOR_NODE';`

Comment: You're welcome. Could you please consider accepting the answer as it seems to help according community traditions and guidelines. A green mark will give a future visibility that the solution is verified.